# How to upload an image without background

Tags: html, image, background, transparency

I did a profile image like the picture below.
I cut the image with the Adobe Photoshop App. So, the image exported as I liked. But, when I uploaded the image when I wrote the code, I noticed that there is a white background around the image even though I cut the image on photoshop as PNG File.

So, how can I upload an image to my project just where there is a pixel on the image without the background?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #2A5C5D;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

img {
  border: 4px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/avFKN.png" width="75px" height="75px">
  <div class="agent-area"></div>
</div>
```

Around the image above, I added border at 4px. So, the border is the square white around the image.

I will note that my task is to add borders around the image. That will appear around the pixels in the image. That means that the border should appear as circular as the pixels in the picture.

The image with the border, should be like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried to do what you said. And nothing didn't happened.

Comment: Here is the picture. I want to insert a border around the picture. But when I add the border. The border is square around the image after I export a PNG File in a circle picture.

Comment: I think I'm getting it now. This is normally done with a standard rectangular image and border radius, but it can still be done.

Comment: I uploaded a new image. look at him.